# Dovecot does not fetch mail from /var/spool/mail/$user to mail_location

Tags: sendmail, dovecot, mailbox

As seen in the /var/log/maillog when mail received or sent, sendmail saving mails to /var/spool/mail/$user and logging them as **stat=Sent**

When a user try to send or receive mail via imap it is not shown in ~$user/mail/

/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf

```
mail_location = maildir:~/mail:INBOX=~/mail/.INBOX
```

-
Directory and file permissons are correct.

```
[root@mail ~]# ll -d /home/$user/mail
drwx------. 7 $user $user 4096 Oct 25 14:04 /home/$user/mail
```

There is no log about this problem in /var/log/maillog. I am wondering that how to send mail file to user's mail directory?

Comment: How have you integrated dovecot and sendmail? [sendmail's configuration changes]

Comment: I didnt integrated them. I think procmail is doing this right? in my sendmail.mc i have these lines  **FEATURE(local_procmail, `', `procmail -t -Y -a $h -d $u')dnl** and **MAILER(procmail)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is INBOX file path was wrong. After changing mail_location from maildir to mbox and INBOX file to /var/spool/mail/%u it gave some permission errors.

```
[root]# vim /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf    
mail_location = mbox:~/:INBOX=/var/spool/mail/%u
```

Errors :

```
failed: Operation not permitted (egid=500)
```

And then setting permissions

```
[root]# chmod 0600 /var/mail*

[root]# service dovecot restart
```

It works well.

Answer (score 4):

Andrzej's comment above is right on; dovecot isn't supposed to automagically do that. You will either need to tell sendmail to put the mail where dovecot is expecting it (or at least tell its local delivery agent to do that), or tell dovecot to expect it where sendmail puts it.

In my case, I do the latter; my `dovecot.conf` includes the line

```
mail_location = mbox:~/:INBOX=/var/spool/mail/%u
```

**Edit**: your sendmail is configured much as mine, using `procmail` as the local MDA.  The man page for procmail suggests that `/var/spool/mail/$user` is the default place that procmail wil put incoming mail, if no other is provided:

> ```
>    /var/spool/mail/$LOGNAME
>                           system mailbox; both the system mailbox and the immediate directory it is in will be created  every
>                           time procmail starts and either one is not present
> ```

so I repeat my point: you can either configure sendmail's MDA, procmail, to put incoming mail in `/home/$user/mail/.INBOX`, or you can configure dovecot to look in `/var/spool/mail/$user`.  But you will have to do one of these things, it's not going to happen by magic.

Answer (score 2):

## Sendmail reconfiguration for integration with dovecot

### http://wiki2.dovecot.org/LDA/Sendmail

For using dovecot for delivery for existing OS use account consider adding the following lines to `sendmail,mc` file [`sendmail.mc` requires compilation into `sendmail.cf`]

```
FEATURE(`local_procmail', `/usr/local/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda',`/usr/local/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda -d $u')
MODIFY_MAILER_FLAGS(`LOCAL', `-f')
```

### Other possible sendmail reconfiguration options

- making sendmail use dovecot only for UIDs no lesser than 1000
  [clasic delivery for system users/accounts, dovecot for normal users]
- making sendmail support deliveries to existing virtual dovecot users [local_procmail based reconfiguration DOES NOT support it]

Comment: how this setting effect `mail_location` behaviour defined in **/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf** ?

Comment: local_procmail based integration will make sendmail use dovecot provided program (dovecot-lda) for deliveries to mailboxes. Dovecot-lda uses dovecot configuration (/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf too).

Answer (score 0):

## Dovecot: INBOX as mbox in /var/mail/username and the rest of the mailboxes in Maildir

If you do not care about sieve filtering then you may configure dovecot to use /var/mail/username as inbox and keep the rest of the user's mailoxes in Maildir format.

It will make dovecot "see" messages delivered by MTA/sendmail to default location - no MTA/sendmail reconfiguration will be required.

http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Namespaces#Mixed_mbox_and_Maildir

Answer (score 0):

You need edit file: /etc/procmailrc

```
# file: /etc/procmailrc
# system-wide settings for procmail
SHELL="/bin/bash"
SENDMAIL="/usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -t"
LOGFILE="/var/log/procmail.log"
DEFAULT="$HOME/Maildir/"
MAILDIR="$HOME/Maildir/"
:0
* ^X-Spam-Status: Yes
.spam/
```

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault.  What did you change in that file?  Can you quote or link to any docs that explain why this works?