# Sendmail and Dovecot almost working but not quite

Tags: sendmail, dovecot

I have set up dovecot as suggested [here.](https://serverfault.com/questions/548638/dovecot-does-not-fetch-mail-from-var-spool-mail-user-to-mail-location/548713#548713)

Mail is delivered to the correct directory and I set my mail_location as suggested:
Dovecot -n yeilds this:

```
disable_plaintext_auth = no
mail_location = mbox:~/:INBOX=/var/spool/mail/%u
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
protocols = pop3
ssl_cert = </etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/pki/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

Permissions on /var/spool/mail are:

```
-rw-rw----   1 dougw      mail       20787737 May 23 20:01 dougw
```

and on the spool/mail directory itself:

```
drwxrwxr-x.  3 root   mail   4096 May 23 20:05 mail
```

and permissions on my home directory .imap are:

```
drwxrwx---    2 dougw mail        4096 May 23 20:08 .imap
```

Yet if I tail maillog (tail -f maillog | grep dougw)

I get this...

```
May 23 19:55:57 pnweb-01 dovecot: pop3-login: Login: user=<dougw>, method=PLAIN, rip=98.164.246.59, lip=10.10.1.63, mpid=4981
May 23 19:55:57 pnweb-01 dovecot: pop3(dougw): Error: chown(/home/dougw/.imap/INBOX, -1, 12(mail)) failed: Operation not permitted (egid=500(dougw), group based on /var/spool/mail/dougw)
May 23 19:55:57 pnweb-01 dovecot: pop3(dougw): Error: mkdir(/home/dougw/.imap/INBOX) failed: Operation not permitted
May 23 19:55:57 pnweb-01 dovecot: pop3(dougw): Error: Couldn't open INBOX: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information. [2014-05-23 19:55:57]
May 23 19:55:57 pnweb-01 dovecot: pop3(dougw): Couldn't open INBOX top=0/0, retr=0/0, del=0/0, size=0
```

If I have mail_location set, what is it trying to do in my home directory anyway? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You have set your `mbox` location to be `~` (your home) and your `INBOX` location to be `/var/spool/mail/dougw` and that is why.

Comment: Is messages delivered by `sendmail` or you have used `dovecot-lda` as delivery agent?